# display two input buttons in a form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I come to you about an issue that I'm having with a contact form that I created using bootstrap see the jsfiddle below for a replica of my code...

My issue is the two buttons that I have for submit and clear are displaying on top of each other for some reason instead of inline next to each other...

I used CSS to format the form contents as table rows, columns and cells all contact labels are in one column and form fields in another *(that's if I got my CSS coded properly)* and I've put the form in a div with bootstrap class of `col-md-6` which will only give it 50% width of the page...

Anyhow like I mentioned my issue is the two buttons are showing under the first column of the table under the labels which I guess is not giving it enough room and as a result the two buttons are stacked on top of each other my question is how would I go about showing the two buttons next to each other by using the full width of the form instead the width of the column??

Here is a link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neenus/nofuvqod/3/

```css
#jumbotron-form {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.90;
}

form {
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0.25em;
}

.form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input {
  display: inline;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-form">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="SUBMIT">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter your name" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Telephone: </label>
        <input type="tel" name="tel" pattern="Telephone" id="tel" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">e-Mail: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@email.ca" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usrmsg">Message: </label>
        <textarea name="message" id="usrmsg" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="enter your message here..."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just posted answer to your query let me know if any further changes are required.

Comment: Thank you Anmol I didn't think of Flex much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HTML5 & Bootstrap markup for your code....

```css
/***********************************************************************************************/


/* Input Field   */


/***********************************************************************************************/

input[type="text"],
input[type="name"],
input[type="phone"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:100%;
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

input[type="text"]:hover:focus,
input[type="name"]:hover:focus,
input[type="phone"]:hover:focus,
input[type="email"]:hover:focus,
textarea:hover:focus {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-width: 280px;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #F5F5F5;
}


/***********************************************************************************************/


/* Button & Reset  */


/***********************************************************************************************/

input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* border radius */
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* prevents bg color from leaking outside the border */
  background-color: #2FB7D5;
  /* layer fill content */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
}

input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
button:hover {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* border radius */
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* prevents bg color from leaking outside the border */
  background-color: #2FB7D5;
  /* layer fill content */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /* inner shadow */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- ================================================
    Contact Form Start
 ================================================= -->

 <section class="contact-form">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
     <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
      <p>
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
      </p>
      
      <p>
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </p>

      <p>
       <label for="message">Message</label>
       <textarea name="" id="message" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Write here..." required></textarea>
      </p>

      <input type="submit" value="Send">
      <input type="reset" value="Write Again">
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Here is my [GitHub](https://github.com/momin-ctg) repository for this contact form

Comment: Momin Thanks very much for your contact form I honestly like it more than what I had but I'm building this freebie static simple site for a friend and she likes it the other way; I would've gone with yours otherwise

Comment: Thanks @Neenus .you can change bootstrap grid as your need and HTML5 markup,moreover CSS3 style is modern cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box for this , here i updated your code please check the snippet and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/nofuvqod/4/)

```css
#jumbotron-form {
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.90;
}

form {
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0.25em;
}

.form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input {
  display: inline;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.submit {
  display: flex;
}

.submit input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-form">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="SUBMIT">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter your name" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Telephone: </label>
        <input type="tel" name="tel" pattern="Telephone" id="tel" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">e-Mail: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usrmsg">Message: </label>
        <textarea name="message" id="usrmsg" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="enter your message here..."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you used `display: table` in `<form>`. I modified your markup and css by adding another `<div>` wrapper for all `.form-group` elements.

Checkout it out: https://jsfiddle.net/nofuvqod/5/

Snippet:

```
#jumbotron-form {
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.90;
}

form {
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing: 0.25em;
}

.form-table{
  display: table;
}

.form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input {
  display: inline;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-form">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="SUBMIT">
      <div class="form-table">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter your name" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tel">Telephone: </label>
          <input type="tel" name="tel" pattern="Telephone" id="tel" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">e-Mail: </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usrmsg">Message: </label>
          <textarea name="message" id="usrmsg" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="enter your message here..."></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Muthu I used this to fix my issue ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the button container with `form-group` class.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</div>
```